# What determines the 'Deal of the Day'

Tags: tribes-ascend

Everyday on the Tribes Ascend home screen there is a "Deal of the Day", a discounted weapon, perk or skin that has its gold cost discounted by a certain percentage. I have a few questions about how these are generated:

- What items can be given out as a deal, is it from a list of all items or simply a certain subset?
- Is the discount amount bound to the item, or can any item have any discount amount?
- Does everyone get the same deal, or is it random per account?

Comment: I imagine the deal of the day is just random for every item at whatever price they give it. And it is the same deal for everyone.

Comment: It's actually not the same for everyone. Only sometimes, it is.

Comment: Thats cool, I thought it was the same. It looks like the deal of the day is something I don't already own. I've never noticed anything so far that i've owned so I guess that would make sense why it's never the same for everyone

Answer (score 6):

I quote from the [Tribes: Ascend patch notes](http://hi-rez.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/454/~/tribes-ascend-version-1.0.961.0-%28tartarus-update)

*"Users will now be presented with a customized “DEAL OF THE DAY.” This is a deal tailored to the individual and presents special pricing on an item that the user does not already own. The timer for the deal of the day resets at the same time as the timer for the First Win of the Day."*

**A few extra details:**

- The deals ***can*** repeat
- They are generated on a person to person basis (They can be the same but it is a 1:[Number of items in the game] chance
- They can occur on any item that you don't have

  - *If you own all the items in the game nothing will show up*
- The percentage you get off an item when it is on "Deal of the Day" is unique to the ***item***

Comment: Sweet. I was right! And to clarify, when I said that it could be the same, this was including the non-Deal-of-the-Day deals such as Raider Pack and such.

Answer (score 5):

*This answer is purely speculation, based on anecdotal evidence.*

1. Usually, your Deal of the Day is not shared among the rest of the community. This is to avoid attempting to sell items and perks to you that you already own.
2. Deals can repeat. Personally, when I've seen a deal repeat, it was the same discount that it had previously been, though this may have been coincidental.
3. Considering the variety of items that I have seen for sale, I suspect that all items can be put on sale, it's just a matter of waiting for it to appear.
4. Deals for classes that you have not purchased will not be displayed, as you have to buy the class beforehand. Instead, you will see deals to buy classes that you have not purchased.

Also, I've seen no evidence that your playing habits affect your deals. For example, if you play a certain class more than others, it will not increase the frequency that you see deals for that class, or vice versa.

Comment: So far, this all lines up with what I've seen. Although what is most interesting to me is I've never seen any of the items from the Assassin bundle, which makes me wonder if bundle items are out.

Comment: That could be an issue of RNG, because I personally just saw the bundle last week.